# SpriteKit (Obj-c) SKSpriteNodes' Positions Not Updating

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, position, skspritenode, nslog

So this is what's going on. I have an SKSpriteNode that isn't global. I make an ivar called `_button1`, and set it to be ***equal*** to the private SKSpriteNode. Later (in`-touchesEnded`), I want to find out what `_button1`'s position is. It works properly at the start-up of the game, except that when `-touchesMoved` changes the position of `_button1`, it isn't recognized in the `NSLog()`. To make things less complicated, here's some code snippets and some explanations.

**1. I have an SKSpriteNode that cannot be accessed except in the for-in statement it's defined in.**

```
SKSpriteNode *button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Test"];
```

**2. I also have an instance variable called `_button1` that can be accessed wherever.**

```
@implementation MainMenuScene
{
  SKSpriteNode *_button1;
}
```

**2. I set `_button1` to be equal to `button`.**

```
_button1 = button;
```

**3. I log the position of `_button1` using `NSLog()`, inside of `-touchesEnded`.**

```
NSLog(@"1 Position.x =\t%.2f", _button1.position.x);

Output: "1 Position.x = 250.00"
```

**4. `-touchesMoved` causes `_button1` to move.**

**5. I log the results again, but the position change hasn't been recognized.**

```
NSLog(@"1 Position.x =\t%.2f", _button1.position.x);

Output: "1 Position.x = 250.00"
```

So what's going on here? I've tried multiple solutions, as well as re-setting the position to be its current position, re-setting `_button1` to be equal to `button`, etc. But it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared some more code rather than just describing your _intent_. The latter is useful in understanding _what_ you want to achieve but you really aren't showing us _how_ you are trying to implement it. A good start would be showing us the code surrounding step 2, and your `touchesMoved` function...

Comment: Well, the `-touchesMoved` doesn't really have any relevance to this except that it moves the `_button`. Basically what my intent is, is that the `NSLog()` will update its position once it moves.

Comment: seriously? You, yourself states in your post that it is the exact place where the position changed isn't recognized. You might be right, but there is no way to help you if you just leave us guessing what your code looks like.

Comment: Without `-touchesMoved:-` we've not much to go on. The code you've posted so far does not explain enough.

Comment: Forget it, I decided to use another solution. But thanks, anyway.